# node js -> Sharepoint behind proxy

Tags: pnp, nodejs

The situation:

- Node Express.js app connects to SharePoint via pnp.js (REST)
- this app MUST route through a proxy

Question:

- How can I force the node express.js app to use the proxy ?

In powershell:

- Invoke-WebRequest https://domain.x : NOK
- Invoke-WebRequest https://domain.x -Proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080 : OK

So I think I need the equivalent of the -Proxy parameter in my Express.js app.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of PnPJS shows how to set a proxy URL when performing the setup: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/nodejs/docs/proxy/

```
import { SPFetchClient, SPOAuthEnv, setProxyUrl } from "@pnp/nodejs";

sp.setup({
    sp: {
        fetchClientFactory: () => {

            // call the set proxy url function and it will be used for all requests regardless of client
            setProxyUrl("{your proxy url}");
            return new SPFetchClient(settings.testing.sp.url, settings.testing.sp.id, settings.testing.sp.secret, SPOAuthEnv.SPO);
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, been busy

I don't have an id, nor a secret. The nodejs app is not a addin. 

I'm logging in on SharePoint onpremise with adfs credentials. 

It works, using pnp-auth, for situations where no corp proxy is in-between.

I cannot get it to work with the proxy though